# Ngx Mat Timepicker

Tags: angular

**ngx-mat-timepicker**
Not able to cancel and submit the time.

<input type="text" class="form-control details-input cursor-pointer" [id]="'timepicker' + i"
[ngxMatTimepicker]="timepicker" matInput [format]="12" readonly placeholder="12:00"
(keydown)="$event.preventDefault()" formControlName="start_time" />
Start Time *
<ng-container
*ngTemplateOutlet="timePickerLogo; context:{ timepicker: timepicker }">
<ngx-mat-timepicker #timepicker [enableKeyboardInput]="true"
(closed)="checkTimingsOverlap(i)">

How to configure cancel button and submit work using keyboard key press.

Comment: Explain your problem some more please. See [Help Center > How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).